# SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected Laravel Spatie Multitenancy

Tags: php, laravel-8

When I is set default => 'tenant' I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
> Laravel Spatie Multitenancy

[image]

I created two databases and two domains:

```
php artisan serve --port=8001
```

In two domain, I got this problem

This is my database file

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => 'tenant',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        
        'tenant' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => null,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
    
        'landlord' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => 'landlord',
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],


        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

This is my multitenancy file

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent;
use Illuminate\Events\CallQueuedListener;
use Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\ForgetCurrentTenantAction;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\MakeQueueTenantAwareAction;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\MakeTenantCurrentAction;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\MigrateTenantAction;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Models\Tenant;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\TenantFinder\DomainTenantFinder;

return [
    /*
     * This class is responsible for determining which tenant should be current
     * for the given request.
     *
     * This class should extend `Spatie\Multitenancy\TenantFinder\TenantFinder`
     *
     */
    "tenant_finder" => DomainTenantFinder::class,

    /*
     * These fields are used by tenant:artisan command to match one or more tenant
     */
    'tenant_artisan_search_fields' => [
        'id',
    ],

    /*
     * These tasks will be performed when switching tenants.
     *
     * A valid task is any class that implements Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchTenantTask
     */
    'switch_tenant_tasks' => [
        Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchTenantDatabaseTask::class,
        \Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\PrefixCacheTask::class,
        // \Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\PrefixCacheTask::class,
        // \Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchTenantDatabaseTask::class,
        // \Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchRouteCacheTask::class,
    ],

    /*
     * This class is the model used for storing configuration on tenants.
     *
     * It must be or extend `Spatie\Multitenancy\Models\Tenant::class`
     */
    'tenant_model' => Tenant::class,

    /*
     * If there is a current tenant when dispatching a job, the id of the current tenant
     * will be automatically set on the job. When the job is executed, the set
     * tenant on the job will be made current.
     */
    'queues_are_tenant_aware_by_default' => true,

    /*
     * The connection name to reach the tenant database.
     *
     * Set to `null` to use the default connection.
     */
    'tenant_database_connection_name' => 'tenant',

    /*
     * The connection name to reach the landlord database
     */
    'landlord_database_connection_name' => 'landlord',

    /*
     * This key will be used to bind the current tenant in the container.
     */
    'current_tenant_container_key' => 'currentTenant',

    /*
     * You can customize some of the behavior of this package by using our own custom action.
     * Your custom action should always extend the default one.
     */
    'actions' => [
        'make_tenant_current_action' => MakeTenantCurrentAction::class,
        'forget_current_tenant_action' => ForgetCurrentTenantAction::class,
        'make_queue_tenant_aware_action' => MakeQueueTenantAwareAction::class,
        'migrate_tenant' => MigrateTenantAction::class,
    ],

    /*
     * You can customize the way in which the package resolves the queuable to a job.
     *
     * For example, using the package laravel-actions (by Loris Leiva), you can
     * resolve JobDecorator to getAction() like so: JobDecorator::class => 'getAction'
     */
    'queueable_to_job' => [
        SendQueuedMailable::class => 'mailable',
        SendQueuedNotifications::class => 'notification',
        CallQueuedListener::class => 'class',
        BroadcastEvent::class => 'event',
    ],

    /*
     * Jobs tenant aware even if these don't implement the TenantAware interface.
     */
    'tenant_aware_jobs' => [
        // ...
    ],

    /*
     * Jobs not tenant aware even if these don't implement the NotTenantAware interface.
     */
    'not_tenant_aware_jobs' => [
        // ...
    ],
];
```

Comment: Did you forget the database name in your configuration?

Comment: I'm using spatie multi databases package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Switch your default connection to
   DB_CONNECTION=landlord
2. Create routes accessible to landlord or
   tenants
3. Add a tenant to the landlord database